# MySQL: Select from list of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if I could select given values from a list and populate rows? For example, `SELECT 1 as one, 2 as two, 3 as three` will populate columns:

```
one    | two    | three
------------------------
1      | 2      | 3
```

I'm looking for a script that populates rows, something like:

```
values
-------
1
2
3
4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can union each one if you want like so

```
SELECT 1 AS numbers
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3
```

a much simpler way to do something like this would be to make a table with an auto incremented id... insert into another column in the table an empty string... then just select the auto incremented id

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    val  varchar(1) 
);
INSERT INTO tmp (val)
values
(""),
(""),
(""),
(""),
(""),
(""),
(""),
(""),
(""),
("");
select id from tmp;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e93a6/1/0)

Comment: Is there any array-like function? `SELECT LIST(1,2,3) AS numbers`.

Comment: @drux no SQL doesn't have array functions.. it has tables which you can basically use as arrays.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks, @John Rudell.

Comment: @drux see my edit.. you can also make a temp table.. insert in some values and pull out the auto incremented id :)

Answer (score 4):

To get a few numbers, the approach from John Ruddell is the probably the most convenient, I can easily incorporate an inline view in any query I'm needing to run.

When I need a lot of numbers, for example, 1 through 4000, I can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE digit (d INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO digit (d) VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

SELECT thousands.d*1000+hundreds.d*100+tens.d*10+ones.d+1 AS n
  FROM digit ones
 CROSS
  JOIN digit tens
 CROSS
  JOIN digit hundreds
 CROSS
  JOIN digit thousands
 WHERE thousands.d < 4
```

I can also add a `HAVING` clause if the boundaries of the numbers I need aren't quite as neat, e.g

```
HAVING n >= 121
   AND n <= 2499
```

If I want to ensure the "numbers" are returned in order, I'll add an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY n
```